# geographic location uri scheme

Tags: uri

I'd like to use a URI scheme to enable the users of one of my apps to share geographic locations.

I don't want to invent my own URI scheme and "geo" seems the most appropriate but there are only two Internet Drafts on the subject ([draft-mayrhofer-geo-uri-01](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-mayrhofer-geo-uri-01), [draft-mayrhofer-geo-uri-02](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-mayrhofer-geo-uri-02)), both expired and wildly different in the way they approach the standard.

Is there an URI that's suited for encoding latitude and longitude and that made it as an RFC? Should I use a generic URI such as [the tag URI scheme](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc4151.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [latest draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-mayrhofer-geopriv-geo-uri-01) is from February 12, 2009. looks like the way to go.

Comment: The proper URL is in Alex's answer - this one's a dead link.

Answer (score 2):

final note: The draft is now in the RFC Editors queue within the IETF, so it should become an RFC within the next 3 - 5 months.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-geopriv-geo-uri-07

Answer (score 1):

The geo URI scheme definition is now RFC 5870 (since June 2010):

http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc5870