# How to generate a location link that will open in default mapping app?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, web-applications, dictionary, apple-maps

I am writing a simple little web app in JS an want to generate links to locations (lat/lon) that will open in a mobile user's default, native mapping app (vs opening in browser).

e.g. Maps on iOS, Google Maps on Android, etc

Any best practices to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't believe that there is any sort of "geolocation" standard tag attribute; I'm not even sure what tag it'd involve. An `<a>` tag has to have a URL if it's going to do anything, so perhaps it'd be some sort of "location" URL scheme.  Perhaps somebody else knows.

Comment: ... something like [this](http://www.bigfraud.org/geoloc/) I guess, which looks like a good start but I've never seen it in use.

Comment: ... and then there's [this Stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637840/geographic-location-uri-scheme) with a link to an IETF proposal for something essentially similar.

Comment: ... and hey [check this out!](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the url scheme and generate a link like this.
When the user clicks on the link, it should open a native mapping app instead.

```
<a href="comgooglemaps://?center=40.765819,-73.975866&zoom=14&views=traffic">Open map</a>
```

Here is the references:

iOS map
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html

Google map in iOS
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme

Google map in Android
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html

Hope these links can help you.

Answer (score 3):

I also have a similar requirement in one of my projects.I did something like this:

```
<a href=geo:latitude,longitude></a>
```

Comment: Doesn't work on MacOS Safari (tested with Ventura 13.4, Safari 16.5)